# Can I use a .cs file in a SharePoint WebPart

Tags: development, web-part

When creating SharePoint WebParts what is the proper way to go about accessing common methods. For example when developing in .net webforms you can add a .cs file to the App_Code folder and consume classes and methods from that file.

I want to be able to create common code that is shared among all my SharePoint WebParts.

Any ideas? Perhaps I am going about this totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a class library, and place your code in there.  You can then deploy this library to your sharepoint farm as part of a solution (.wsp file).

You can create .wsp files in a number of ways.  The optimal method depends on your version of SharePoint.

If you are using SharePoint 2010, just create a SharePoint project in Visual Studio and add your code to the project.  VS will build the .wsp file for you for deployment.

Here's a good getting started guide for SharePoint 2010 development : http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/Pages/Developer-Training-Guide.aspx

Comment: So what you are saying is that if I create a .cs file within a .wsp solution and deploy it to my SharePoint Farm it's namespace will then be available in all future .wsp files?

Comment: A .wsp package is just a deployment vessel.  Your code will get compiled into a .dll and deployed to the GAC on the target machines (or the BIN directory, if you choose).  At that point, you can reference the assembly like you normally would.

Comment: If you are planning for a shared library, I would put it in it's own solution (.sln and .wsp). That will allow you to manage deployments better.